# Print document multiple times with js print

Tags: javascript, html, printing

how can i get multiple prints with java-script print function without using or even showing the select printer properties wizard? i want that it automatically selects the default printer and sends print request fixed number of times. Any suggestions??

Comment: "without using or even showing the select printer properties wizard" - unfortunately I hope this isn't possible, otherwise a malicious website could spam the hell out of my printer before I knew what was going on

Comment: what about printing on some onclick event? like calling a myPrintFunction which calls window.print() function?

Comment: i think i sound silly. Do i?